# How to embed a link in a UITextView for the iphone

Tags: iphone, safari, uitextfield, hyperlink, uitextview

I'm wondering if it is possible to put a hyperlink in a UITextView that will open up safari and take the user to a web page.  And if so how can I accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338229/ios-clickable-text-inside-uitextview#comment19930723_14338229

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yes, you can by setting the dataDetectorTypes property pf the UITextView to 'UIDataDetectorTypeLink '.

Comment: but the link color changed to blue, how to make it as white color?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not at the moment since there are no attributes you can attach to the text.

You have a couple of options

1) Use a UIWebView instead.

2) If the text is in a known position then you could overlay a button on the coordinates.  This is how Twitterific on the iPhone does links,

Comment: This was correct at the time (pre iOS 3) but is no longer the correct answer. See above.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [TTStyledText](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/TTStyledText.m) class from Joe Hewitt's Three20 framework.