# iOS clickable text inside UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, click, uitextview, hyperlink

Is there a way to make clickable parts of UITextView. Actually I want to make text something like

> By clicking “Register” above, you are agreeing to the Terms of Services and Privacy Statement

where Terms of Services should be one link and Privacy Statement another. And by clicking on those I should do something.

Comment: if it is possible in you application, you could use `UIWebView` object with a formatted `HTML` content, and everything can be clickable, and you would be able to handle all of them in your application.

Comment: Yes, I know that solution, but it's some kind of hack :) and I wanted some more elegant solution. 
Thank you!

Comment: it is very costless and powerful solution, if the time does matter... :)

Comment: I agree :)
I tried solution I've marked as Answer and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it with the code above using [this project](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

```
- (void)_configureTermsLabel
{
    self.termsOfUseLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.termsAndConditionsLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.termsOfUseLabel.frame];
    self.termsAndConditionsLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    self.termsAndConditionsLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    self.termsAndConditionsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    NSString *termsStr = NSLocalizedString(@"Terms of use", @"Terms of use");
    NSString *privacyStr = NSLocalizedString(@"Privacy Policy", @"Privacy Policy");
    NSString *andStr = NSLocalizedString(@"and", @"and");
    NSString *conductStr = NSLocalizedString(@"Code of conduct", @"Code of conduct");
    NSString *termsAndConditionsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ %@ %@", termsStr,
                                       privacyStr, andStr, conductStr];
    self.termsAndConditionsLabel.text = termsAndConditionsStr;

    NSString *languageCode = [[GLQAppDelegate sharedDelegate] languageIdentifier];
    NSURL *termsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kGLQTermsOfUseURL, languageCode]];
    NSURL *privacyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kGLQPrivacyPolicyURL, languageCode]];
    NSURL *conductURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kGLQCodeOfConductURL, languageCode]];

    NSRange termsRange = [self.termsAndConditionsLabel.text rangeOfString:termsStr];
    NSRange privacyRange = [self.termsAndConditionsLabel.text rangeOfString:privacyStr];
    NSRange conductRange = [self.termsAndConditionsLabel.text rangeOfString:conductStr];

    [self.termsAndConditionsLabel addLinkToURL:termsURL withRange:termsRange];
    [self.termsAndConditionsLabel addLinkToURL:privacyURL withRange:privacyRange];
    [self.termsAndConditionsLabel addLinkToURL:conductURL withRange:conductRange];
    self.termsAndConditionsLabel.delegate = self;

    self.termsAndConditionsLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.termsAndConditionsLabel];
}
```

Comment: So you didn't use UITextView. Is it impossible to do with UITextView?

Comment: @NSGodMode I haven't tried to do this using UITextView