# How to make html link within NSString?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring

I have NSString as follows

```
NSString *textOutStations = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello Everyone. Please check out website:<br> http://www.google.com/</br>"];
```

I want to show google.com as below in URL, as I will load this in UIWebView.

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

So, whenever user click it, It must open Safari in iPhone.

Comment: mm..put <a teg inside NSString object: @"<a href=\"URL\">Hello...</a>"

Comment: can you make, I tried, but found some errors?

Comment: How are you displaying this? UILabel, UITextField, UIWebView?

Comment: Side Note - Why are you using `stringWithFormat:`? You don't have any format specifiers. Just do `NSString *textOutStations = @"Hello Everyone. Please check out website:<br> http://www.google.com/</br>";`.

Comment: I did it by using UIWebView link checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *textOutStations = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello Everyone. Please check out website:<br> <a href=\"google.com\">http://www.google.com/</a>"];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:textOutStations baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Then in UIWebView delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    // Opening safari
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];

....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your method to open it in Safari, and I click link to detect it.

Comment: Dear, this method opening link in Safari, along with within WebView, now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
NSString *textOutStations = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><div> Hello Everyone. Please check out website:<br/> <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\"> http://www.google.com/ </a>  </div></body></html>";

[self.webView loadHTMLString:textOutStations baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

This will help you......

Comment: Thanks, but see Injections comment, another issue is there

Answer (score 1):

You can not specify a URL with in a string and have it be clickable, this type of functionality is dependant on the object to which is using it, aka, `UITextView` `UITextField` `UILabel` `UIWebView` etc,

A `UIWebview` will show your url with in the webview it will not open the link in safari. IF you want to load it in ui web view, it's already ansered above, if you want to open it in safari, you have to do

```
[[UIAplication sharedApplication] openUrl:urlObject];
```

if you want to open it to be text with in a `UITextView` i would suggest this other stack overflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338229/ios-clickable-text-inside-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I checked the link option in Attribute Inspector of UIWebView and it detected the link.

Method to OPEN in SAFARI...

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```